# How is the threshold probability $p_c$ defined for oriented site percolation?

Tags: terminology, percolation

The threshold probability for unoriented site percolation is such that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{P}_{p} & = & \underset{v\in\mathbb{\mathbb{L}}^{d}}{\prod}\mu_{v}\\
\theta(p) & = & \mathbb{P}_{p}(\mid C\mid=\infty)\\
p_{c} & = & \text{sup}\{p\mid\theta(p)=0\}
\end{eqnarray*}

as given by [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SitePercolation.html). I cannot find similar definitions for oriented site percolation such as [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrientedPercolationModel.html). So

**How is the oriented threshold probability defined for oriented site percolation?**